# When does tvOS purge user data

Tags: core-data, cloudkit, tvos, apple-tv

Does anyone know what events will cause tvOS to purge temp user data on Apple TV? I'm assuming that it will be things like when it needs space to cache movies and other iTunes content. Does this also apply for streaming offline content (i.e. streaming things from local servers in a non-internet connected environment)?

I have a client who wants an Apple TV version of their app. Data is currently stored using CoreData. I will be using CloudKit to sync that data with iCloud. However, the problem is that my client may not have the Apple TV connected to the internet at all times. My concern is if they make a bunch of entries (small data, on the order of a few MBs, max) while the unit is offline. If they *never* connect the unit to the internet so it can sync with iCloud, is it still possible that OS will purge that use data?

If it still may be purged, what are other options? I know we only get 500kb of NSUserDefaults storage, which is not going to be enough space for my needs.

My assumption is that if the Apple TV is not connect to the internet and not downloading and streaming content from iTunes, the OS will not have a need to purge anything and the user data should be safe.

Can anyone comment on this, or point to some documentation in some magical hidden location on the Apple Developer portal?